# Eclipse displaying error but not giving error in console

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to run my application but it is displaying error in the project explorer
I had **try to clean my application many time** even **restart the eclipse** but no effect 
It is displaying error and also **it is not giving me any error** in the console.
How to fix this issue?

[image]

**EDIT**

And also I remove all the reference lib and add again but still getting error.

Comment: Try Restore from Local History if you have edited something recently.

Comment: I solve my issue by deleting the debug.keystore

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please follow the steps on [this](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/eclipse-throws-debug-certificate-expired/) link. That user has the same problem. I have given answer there.

**EDIT**

solve this issue by following below steps

1. Go to Window => Show View => Problems
2. Now I can see the error like `debug certificate expired`
3. Now `Delete the file ~/home/.android/debug.keystore`
4. Clean Project

For more information refer [this](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/eclipse-throws-debug-certificate-expired/) link

Comment: No effect after following your steps

Comment: have you seen Sweety's last comment on his question ?

Comment: I mean this comment "Hi all thanks for all your valuable responses....I found the solution....I have deleted the .keystore file and now I am able to run all my eclipse projects. – Sweety 47 mins ago"

Comment: Ohh that I did not see. Thanks this is my exact solution

Answer (score 2):

Check the problems and fix that. To view the problems == Window -> Show View -> Problems

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem in the added library function, check the library files what you had added to this app. it shows error there remove it once and add again..

**or**

rightclick-->Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties..

Comment: No effect after removing and adding the reference library