# Eclipse error : Your project contains error(s),please fix them

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt

I am using Eclipse Classic 3.7.2 working only on Android. I use Ubuntu as my OS. When I run any basic Android application on Eclipse say "Hello World", it results an error called `Your Project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.`

Now I have googled and checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954316/your-project-contains-errors-please-fix-it-before-running-it) and may others but I did not get the solution.

I also tried `Project > clean...` but it isn't working.

`Windows->Show Views->Problems` shows 2 errors:

1. Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException:/home/android/Desktop/helloworld/bin/resources.ap_does not exist.
2. Unable to parse aapt...

Comment: try to clean you project and rebuild

Comment: i had done it, even deleted keystore ... but results the same ..

Comment: give you some advice:`1.try close the project and reopen;2.can modify the xml file like string.xml or layout xml file whatever you like to make the resource change`

Comment: you have to set workspace for that.and i sugess plz make workspace in local drive not in desktop and then try.. i think your error seen u r missing some file so first check in xml file any thing missing or nt. if red line occur then its containss erro and then solve it

Comment: make a new project and copy all classes and xml files.It will work.

Answer (score 3):

It may be be because of Eclipse's debug certificate expiration.

Please look at to my this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967222/eclipse-displaying-error-but-not-giving-error-in-console/8967244#8967244).

Answer (score 2):

Close and restart Eclipse. It works everytime !

Its bug with deleting android projects I think.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced exactly same type of issue. Just update your eclipse ADT plugin to latest version.

After update clean build the project.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your .android folder and delete your debug certificate. In my computer it is in this path

```
E:\Users\(ur profyle)\.android
```

Inside that there is a file name '**debug.keystore**'. Delete that,clean and try to build the project again. Sometimes this error is caused when the certificate expires.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Eclipse to the latest available version(Indigo) and then need to update the ADT(level 16 I think), as the latest ADT updates works on Indigo only. After the updates close and reopen the Eclipse, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Android sdk path once again and restart Eclipse.  It fixes the issue (window-preferences-android-sdklocation).

Or, just update your Android tools and restart Eclipse works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project `Properties -> Java Build Path`

Select Libraries and remove Android Dependencies

After this my problem solved.

The error was because of updating

Answer (score 0):

Check your libs folder .. 
some libraries cause this , 
it happened to me once and i was use Apache POI .. i tried to delete the jars from libs folder and it's worked ..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Eclipse after executing `Project => Clean..`. That option deletes all the compiled stuff from your project and, therefore, the java classes start looking like if they all have errros.

To fix that problem I had to:
1. open my java clases and XML layout files(for android dev) 
2. do a small change, something like a adding a space 
3. Hitting Crt+S to ask eclipse to save and compile the class once again.

This solution may or may not work for you. I recommend looking at your specific problems using the *Problems tab* of Eclipse (Found at `Windows=>Show View=>Problems`) since it tells you about the exact errors and other very useful information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using android support library make sure you have not added jar files ( *android-support-v4.jar* and *android-support-v7-appcompat.jar* ) in your libs folder.
you only need to add *android-support-v7-appcompat* as library on your project.
It worked for me the time I had the same issue

Answer (score -1):

My project had no errors in it but I noticed another open (unrelated) project which did have errors. I closed that project and my other project worked fine again.

Now the "unrelated" project used to be related but I'd removed the dependency ages ago. Closing it solved my problem so I have to assume there is some Eclipse bug in there somewhere which is still linking to it in some way. I'd say if I created a new project and copied everything in it might have achieved the same result.

As a test for yourself.. maybe close all other projects except the one you are working on.